# Dialogflow Account linking breaks the flow

Tags: google-oauth, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm developing a chatbot in Dialogflow for Google Assistant, I made sign-in compulsory(using authorization code flows) in Account Linking Section from Actions on Google using [this official documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking), so when I invoke a bot it asks for a sign in if a user not already signed in.

After the sign-in, it breaks the flow, and I need to again invoke my bot as shown in this image.

**I want to make this flow continuous, instead of invoking a bot again, it should open the Default Welcome Intent once the linking process finished.**

[image]

> This is my linking setup

[image]

> PS: I'm using python webhook for processing queries of other intents
>   but not for Default Welcome Intent.

This is my integration setup

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use Google Signin to handle Account Linking. It does not break the flow and you can access user profile details in parameters of your intent webhook.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in

Answer (score 0):

please make sure,

1. you have entered a valid callback URL.
2. your backend server(where authentication happens) should redirect to provided callback URL